Angular Directive Failing to Affect Input Fields in Child and Grandchild Components
I’m having trouble getting my Angular directive to work on input fields that are located in child and grandchild components. While the directive functions correctly for input fields that are directly within the component to which I’ve applied it, it does not seem to propagate down to nested input fields.
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input',
  standalone: true,
})
export class BlurDirective {
  @HostListener('blur', ['$event'])
  blur($event: Event): void {
    console.log('blur');
  }
}

Here is my directive as stated before it triggers when I add an input field directly and leave the field, but does not work for all the input fields in the child and grandchild components

Can you please share the detailed code?

@Viji_Pykara There isn't much more code than the directive that gets imported into the parent component. Within this component, input field components are used. If I add the directive to the input field component as well, it works, but that's not a valid solution for me, as it would result in the directive being added throughout my entire app.

UPDATE:
You can adjust the directive to accept a attribute which will enable disable the functionality.
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[inputBlur]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class BlurDirective {
  @HostListener('blur', ['$event'])
  blur($event: Event): void {
    console.log('blur');
  }
}

After doing this, you can add the attribute inputBlur to the input elements you want to have this functionality, it will work only for the ones you set.
E.g.
<input type="text" inputBlur/>


Make sure you add the directive to the imports array which applies for two conditions.
If the component is standalone -> the imports should be in the imports array of the component.
If the component is not standalone -> go to the module, where the component is added to the declarations array and add the import
...

@Component({

  ...
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BlurDirective],
  ...
})
export class GrandParentComponent {
  ...
}


I tried this, and it works when I add the directive inside the input field component. However, this is not a viable solution for me, as it would apply the directive and event to every instance of the input field across my entire app, since the input field is a standalone component.
